# How to use collection in B2X virtual method in IBM WODM8.x

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I am trying to use collection(list) in b2x virtual method

B2X Method - arguments -

```
add(Double d,List l)
l.add(d);
```

But when I write rules it does not allow List object. What is wrong here?

Comment: Which problem you got?

Comment: while authoring rules, it does not allow variable of java.util.List type. Do we have any info/urls on collection with bom, apart from IBM information center.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the list to an array.  You can then iterate over the array with a for loop:

```
Object[] things = paymentsRepo.payments.toArray();

for(int n=0; n <things.length; n++)
{
... etc
```